# How to install a custom SMT in confluent kafka docker installation?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to do event streaming between mysql and elasticsearch, one of the issue I faced was with the JSON object in mysql when transfered to elasticsearch was in JSON string format not as an object.

I was looking for a solution using SMT, I found this,

> https://github.com/RedHatInsights/expandjsonsmt

I don't know how to install or load in my kafka or connect container

Here's my docker-compose file,

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    mem_limit: 1024m
    mem_reservation: 256m
    cpus: 3.0


  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    mem_limit: 2048m
    mem_reservation: 256m
    cpus: 3.0


  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    mem_limit: 256m
    mem_reservation: 128m
    cpus: 3.0


  connect:
    image: confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      extra_hosts:
        host.docker.internal: host-gateway
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.2.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
    mem_limit: 1024m
    mem_reservation: 256m
    cpus: 3.0


  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.2.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
    mem_limit: 512m
    mem_reservation: 256m
    cpus: 3.0

      
  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
    mem_limit: 256m
    mem_reservation: 256m
    cpus: 3.0
```

Here's my confluent kafka connect, Dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0

RUN   confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.5.1 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:1.5.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.2.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mongodb:1.5.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch:11.0.6 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.2.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/connect-transforms:latest
```

I tried adding this line in Dockerfile of confluent kafka connect, like  it mentioned in that github readme file

```
COPY ./kafka-connect-smt-expandjsonsmt-0.0.7-assemble-all.jar $KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR
```

It didn't work because `KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR` was empty I tried `echo $KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR` to verify it.

Can anyone help out how I can install this custom SMT into my docker installation of kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That connector exists on the Hub as well

`confluent-hub install redhatinsights/expandjsonsmt:0.0.7`

https://www.confluent.io/hub/redhatinsights/expandjsonsmt

Comment: Thanks a lot, When I tried to copy the jar file to plugin path it didn't work but installing it from confluent-hub worked. It seems when doing custom installation I have to do some other configuration for it to work, maybe.

Comment: `enviromment` values provided to compose are not available at container build time, so the COPY command in the question will not work, no. Otherwise, the other answer is correct in that you need to copy that JAR and any needed dependencies if not a fat JAR into its own folder under the plugin path

Answer (score 1):

to install SMT it just the same as installing other connector,

Copy your custom SMT JAR file (and any non-Kafka JAR files required by the transformation) into a directory that is under one of the directories listed in the plugin.path property in the Connect worker configuration –

In your case copy to `/usr/share/confluent-hub-components`

Comment: Should I copy the .jar file alone to "CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH" or create a folder inside the CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH and then copy the .jar file?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html

Comment: Copy your custom SMT JAR file (and any non-Kafka JAR files required by the transformation) into a directory that is under one of the directories listed in the plugin.path property in the Connect worker configuration